# Python multiprocessing error with Manager

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a class like this:

```
class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.manager = Manager()
        self.ls = self.manager.list()
        
    def clear(self):
        with Manager() as manager:
            self.ls = manager.list()

    @property
    def queue(self):
        return list(self.ls)
```

If I call

```
q = Queue()
q.clear()
print(q.queue)
```

then it returns error

```
  File "C:\Users\test.py", line 17, in queue
    return list(self.ls)
  File "<string>", line 2, in __len__
  File "E:\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\managers.py", line 806, in _callmethod
    self._connect()
  File "E:\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\managers.py", line 793, in _connect
    conn = self._Client(self._token.address, authkey=self._authkey)
  File "E:\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 505, in Client
    c = PipeClient(address)
  File "E:\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\connection.py", line 707, in PipeClient
    _winapi.WaitNamedPipe(address, 1000)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

but if I change the `clear` method to

```
    def clear(self):
        self.ls = self.manager.list()
```

then things run correctly.

What is this error, why does it happen?

Comment: Can I ask why are you creating a new manager in clear?

Comment: @PratikThakare If the line `with Manager() ...` is what you are asking about, then it's because I don't know clearly about the `Manager()`. Since in the doc's example, they use context manager with `Manager`, I tried to follow it as I was guessing maybe they need to close something by the end of the program.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are abstracting the use of `Manager` you cannot use context managers in that way. What you did just created a new `Manager` object and a shared list. You can try something like

```py
class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.manager = Manager()
        self.ls = self.manager.list()

    def clear(self):
        self.ls = self.manager.list()

    @property
    def queue(self):
        return list(self.ls)

    def __del__(self):
        self.manager.shutdown()
```

The `shutdown()` method is what is called by the __exit__() of the context manager, as written in the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.managers.BaseManager.address).

If you want to use context managers you can inherit the Manager and then use context manager when you use the class and it's methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can created a context manager for your `Queue` class by implementing `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods. Then we have:

```py
from multiprocessing import Manager

class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.manager = Manager()
        self.started = True
        self.ls = self.manager.list()

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.manager.shutdown()
        self.started = False

    def __del__(self):
        if self.started:
            self.manager.shutdown()

    def clear(self):
        assert self.started
        self.ls = self.manager.list()

    def append(self, o):
        assert self.started
        self.ls.append(o)
        return self

    @property
    def queue(self):
        assert self.started
        return list(self.ls)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Queue() as q:
        print(q.queue)
        q.append(1)
        print(q.queue)
        q.clear()
        print(q.queue)

    # This should raise an AssertionException:
    print(q.queue)
```

Prints:

```None
[]
[1]
[]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Booboo\test\test.py", line 43, in <module>
    print(q.queue)
  File "C:\Booboo\test\test.py", line 31, in queue
    assert self.started
AssertionError
```

If you want to define your `Queue` class so that it must be used as a context manager, then:

```py
from multiprocessing.managers import SyncManager

class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.manager = None

    def _test_entered(self):
        if not self.manager:
            raise Exception('You are accessing this Queue instance without it being used as a context manager.')

    def __enter__(self):
        self.manager = SyncManager()
        self.manager.start()
        self.clear()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.manager.shutdown()
        self.manager = None

    def clear(self):
        self._test_entered()
        self.ls = self.manager.list()

    def append(self, o):
        self._test_entered()
        self.ls.append(o)
        return self

    @property
    def queue(self):
        self._test_entered()
        return list(self.ls)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    q = Queue()
    # Another way of using a Queue instance as a context manager
    with q:
        print(q.queue)
        q.append(1)
        print(q.queue)
        q.clear()
        print(q.queue)
    # The SysncManager process is shut down now

    # Now we start a new SyncManager process:
    with q:
        print(q.queue)
        q.append(1)
        print(q.queue)
        q.clear()
        print(q.queue)
    # The SyncManager process is once again shut down now

    # This should raise an Exception:
    q.clear()
```

Prints:

```None
[]
[1]
[]
[]
[1]
[]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Booboo\test\test.py", line 56, in <module>
    q.clear()
  File "C:\Booboo\test\test.py", line 22, in clear
    self._test_entered()
  File "C:\Booboo\test\test.py", line 9, in _test_entered
    raise Exception('You are accessing this Queue instance without it being used as a context manager.')
Exception: You are accessing this Queue instance without it being used as a context manager. raise an Exception:
    q.clear()
```

Note that the `__del__` method is not required now since the `SyncManager` process will be shut down when the context manager exits. We have also replaced the `assert` statement with a method call.